# Set gradient to MKCircle

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, gradient, mkoverlay

I need to set a gradient to `MKCircle`s so that it resembles a heat map.
Is it possible?

Or should I create an image with all the circles and then hook it to the map with a overlay?

Comment: Can you show an example of or give more detail of what effect you`re trying to achieve?  There's an example of a gradient polygon overlay in the Location Awareness Programming Guide.

Comment: Are you sure that circles are the correct way to go? Have you looked at the HazardMap sample code (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HazardMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010049-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)? It draws a heat map of earthquakes onto a map view.

Comment: I want a similar result as the HazardMap but I dont have so many points just some and I need to make circles with gradient getting a similar result as the hazard map, it`s quite close to this, http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/building-an-earthquake-monitor-for-iphone-using-mapkit